# Complex referencing in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a sheet in excel that will have a complex referencing system and need help.

It is a rota and one sheet will contain the rota for a given week, the other sheet has the 'master rota'. The week rota just contains the list of people who are on call. The master rota has a list of shifts for each person.

I need the 'week rota' to correctly identify who is on call for the appropriate week number as stated on the week rota. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by a "rota". It would help a lot if you would (1) define it, and (2) show an illustration of your data, including an indication of what results you want Excel to determine for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use one sheet set up as a table, with columns for the week and the persion.  The rows would cover all weeks e.g. your "master rota".  I would then use the Table Filters to review by person and/or by week.

There's no obvious need for formulas or complexity.